# Meaning of colors in histogram matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram

l have a numpy variable called rnn1 of dimension(37,512)

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(rnn1, histtype='stepfilled')
```

l got the following histogram shape

[image: histogram]

**To what the different colors refer ?**
What is the difference between `n` and `patches`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As the documentation of `hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) states: input x can be an array of shape `(n,)` or **a sequence of `(n,)` arrays**. Since you are passing an array of shape `(37,512)`, matplotlib interprets this as a sequence of 512 different (37,)-long arrays. It therefore draws 512 histogram, each with a different color. I'm guessing that's not actually what you were trying to achieve, but that's outside the scope of your question.

The returned value `n` is a list of 512 arrays, each containing the height of each of the bars in your histograms.

The returned object `patch` is a list of 512 lists of patches, which are the actual graphical elements that compose the figure.